# iPhone Bonjour From Background

Tags: iphone, background, bonjour

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses Bonjour Services, and I have the following question:

When the app is sent to background, I need to close my Bonjour service; when the app comes to foreground, how do I restart my Bonjour service?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods. Specifically, I would take a look at [applicationDidBecomeActive:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive%3a) and [applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a). When it becomes active, start Bonjour; when it enters background, stop it.